# Product Attribute not display under Catalog Product List conditions

Tags: magento2, php, database, magento2.4

I created attribute for configurable products. I want to create a page using that attribute. I selected the Catalog Product List option in widget.
But i can not see added attribute in the dropdown.

Please find the attachments and help me.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported, which state that Magento exclude attributes that have the Catalog Input Type for Store Owner (`frontend_input`) set to **Text Field**. It has been fixed in Magento **2.4.6**.

The related Git commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/008205bd0dca913a17a161d805dfcf66da4f2e69

Based on this change, I have created a patch for Magento 2.4.4 and 2.4.5:

```
diff --git a/vendor/module-catalog-widget/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php b/vendor/module-catalog-widget/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php
index 41f23d9..6927e10 100644
--- a/vendor/module-catalog-widget/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php
+++ b/vendor/module-catalog-widget/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php
@@ -9,7 +9,6 @@
  */
 namespace Magento\CatalogWidget\Model\Rule\Condition;

-use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductCategoryList;
 use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
 use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
@@ -87,9 +86,7 @@ class Product extends \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Product\AbstractProduct
         $productAttributes = array_filter(
             $productAttributes,
             function ($attribute) {
-                return $attribute->getFrontendLabel() &&
-                    $attribute->getFrontendInput() !== 'text' &&
-                    $attribute->getAttributeCode() !== ProductInterface::STATUS;
+                return $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
             }
         );
```

For instructions on how to apply composer patches, please refer to this document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html?lang=en#composer